# Cómo escalar varias imágenes un mismo factor con CSS

Tags: css

Tengo una serie de imágenes que se van construyendo incrementalmente, es decir, cada una es igual a la anterior más alguna otra cosa. Por ejemplo (ejecutar el snippet para ver las imágenes):

```html
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ8uV.png"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7z3Y.png"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8DmG.png"/></div>
```

El resultado es demasiado grande y quiero reducirlo, digamos por ejemplo a la mitad.

No puedo usar el atributo `width=50%`, porque eso me reduciría cada figura al 50% de su contenedor (el `<div>`) y por tanto aplicará un factor de escala distinto a cada figura. Por ejemplo, el texto contenido en cada caja tiene diferente tamaño según la figura. Ejecutar el siguiente snippet para entender qué quiero decir:

```html
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ8uV.png" style="width:50%"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7z3Y.png" style="width:50%"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8DmG.png" style="width:50%"/></div>
```

La siguiente idea es usar `transform: scale(0.5)`. Eso sí reduce todas las figuras por igual, el mismo factor de escala, pero deja un espacio en blanco alrededor porque no reduce su caja.

```html
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ8uV.png" style="transform: scale(0.5)"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7z3Y.png" style="transform: scale(0.5)"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8DmG.png" style="transform: scale(0.5)"/></div>
```

(Tampoco entiendo por qué cada nueva imagen sale más desplazada a la derecha, pero bueno).

Usando javascript podría averiguar las dimensiones en pixels de cada imagen, dividir por dos y forzar el estilo a un ancho en pixels. Pero no quiero usar javascript si puedo evitarlo.

Así pues, la pregunta es ¿cómo puedo reducir todas las imágenes en un mismo factor de escala usando CSS, sin javascript, y sin que quede ese espacio en blanco alrededor?

Answer (score 6):

El problema al usar scale es cómo se hace el render: se coloca todo en su sitio y luego se escala usando como origen el centro. Los elementos que puedan estar a la derecha o a la izquierda no deben moverse, así que se crean huecos.
Una posible solución es definir como el origen la esquina izquierda superior:

```css
img {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ8uV.png" style="transform: scale(0.5)"/></div>

<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7z3Y.png" style="transform: scale(0.5)"/></div>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8DmG.png" style="transform: scale(0.5)"/></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero el problema no era sólo que me salieran desplazados, sino también el espacio alrededor, que implica que salen más separados verticalmente de lo que les rodea. Y el float left puede interferir en el flujo del párrafo ¿si las imágenes eran parte de un texto?

Answer (score 4):

> ¿cómo puedo reducir todas las imágenes en un mismo factor de escala usando CSS, sin javascript, y sin que quede ese espacio en blanco alrededor?

#### Solución:

Podrías usar [`zoom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom)

```html
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ8uV.png" style="zoom: .5"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7z3Y.png" style="zoom: .5"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8DmG.png" style="zoom: .5"/></div>
```

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que en Firefox no funciona :`(

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que la mejor solución a tu problema, sería establecer una escala a la mitad y corregir el origen de transformación en el eje X = 0 mientras que los margenes de arriba y abajo los puedes resolver usando porcentajes negativos. Ej:

```css
div img{
  margin: -1.5em 0;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 0 50%; /*Evita que se corran a la izq*/
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ8uV.png"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7z3Y.png"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8DmG.png"/></div>
```

El problema con esta solución es que si la imagen que cargas es de un tamaño que excede el ancho total del documento, este va producir un desborde del flujo y producir una barra de desplazamiento horizontal.

Esto lo ultimo lo puedes resolver, añadiendo un ancho maximo del 100% del contenedor o del viewport usando la unidad de medida: 100vw, pero causaría que las imágenes más anchas se reduzcan y pierdan la proporción en comparación con las menos anchas.

```css
div img{
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: auto; /*Esto es por prevenir que las proporciones se distorsionen en ciertos navegadores*/
  margin: -1.5em 0;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 0 50%; 
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ8uV.png"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7z3Y.png"/></div>
<hr/>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8DmG.png"/></div>
```

Comment: Ahora, esos cuadros que vas a ir agregando uno al lado de otro y otro más abajo, tienen algún límite en número? Es decir maximo agregaras 4 o 5 en horizontal o en vertical serán maximo 10 o algo asi? Por que si es un sí, se podría hacer una medida dinámica teniendo en cuenta el ancho del contenedor.